# passing project.properties file to sonar-scanner

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

i have multiple projects in one solution file. and need to build 3 projects in one pipeline and two projects in another pipeline of CI. So in order to have code analyzed using sonarqube, i found that using two project.properties file and by running sonar-scanner command in the directory of the solution file as well as the properties file serves the issue.

this is working if i include 3 projects in one sonar-project.properties file. because im not passing any arguments along with sonar-scanner it is picking default properties file i.e., sonar-project.properties . if i rename it and create another properties file for the other pipeline, i need to pass the arguments as

sonar-scanner -Dproject.settings=../myproject.properties

but it is not recognizing the properties file.  Please help.

I followed this link: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages
Sonarqube version = 6.8
pipeline in TFS 2017.
MSBuild version 15.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kaushik Kv, any update on this, have your issue been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the using the traditional properties file under solution/project folder,  you could directly use it in Additional properties setting of **[SonarQube](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube)** task with version 4.0

[image]

> One of the best improvements of this new preparation task, is that the
>   single line “Additional properties” is replaced by a multi-line
>   textbox which allows you to set all the properties as you would
>   normally do in the “sonar-project.properties” file.

More details take a look at this blog: [Perform SonarCloud and SonarQube analysis with the new version 4 build tasks](https://medium.com/@edwin.vriethoff/perform-a-sonarcloud-analysis-on-script-based-projects-7052d456bcf7)

Answer (score 2):

When you try to pass the sonar properties file through the argument `project.settings` do you have also a file named sonar-project.properties in the analysis folder? If so you have to rename it in order to use the project.settings argument.

I have noticed that if a sonar-project.properties file already exists, the file pass through the project.settings argument is not taken in to account.

Instead of using .properties files, an other option to  only analyze specific projects is to use MSBuild conditionnal exclusion in csprojs. 
The complete description is available at : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-.net-documentation/blob/master/doc/appendix-3.md

Comment: i have two properties file. one is Service-sonar-project.properties and the other is Master-sonar-project.properties in the analysis folder. i want to pick one for each pipeline using sonar-scanner arguments.